# 555 - HIGH then long delay

Tags: delay, 555

I trying to create a circuit with only one 555 to send HIGH on output(3) for very short time, like 200ms, then set LOW for something like 20~30 seconds.

Then I'm just need turn on circuit, then: 
a) fast HIGH (~200ms)
b) long LOW (~20-30s)

I already able to make a "default" 555 circuit with stable HIGH/LOW in same timing (1000ms/1000ms), but I'm getting trouble to make this with different HIGH and LOW timmings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General approach is to separate the discharge resistor into two using diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0mf9h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor C2 charges through R1 + R3 and discharges through R2, ignoring diode drops and discharge transistor collector voltage when on.

Approximately, on time is proportional to R1 + R3 and off time is proportional to R2, so you can make the ratio suit your application.

Comment: +1, there is an example of the same thing with adjustable mark to space ration in this question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336785/ne555-based-speed-controller-circuit-contradicting-pins-in-2-tutorials/336790#336790

Comment: Worked great at simulator.  Going to build it now, thanks. http://everycircuit.com/circuit/5064547242344448/555-long-delay

Comment: Both worked, from @Spehro and "555 timer in astable mode: How can I achieve longer low output than high?"  http://everycircuit.com/circuit/5750062543273984